# Calculate sum from a JSON sub object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I start with VueJs and I have a trouble. I try to make sum from JSON sub object but it's not working. I have a global object (**Data**) end sub object (**achat**). I would like to calculate sum for values belonging to key **initial**. I am trying multiple methods, it's not working. I don't speak English. Thanks for your understanding.

I want to have as result: example

```
{
    "data": [

        {
            "id": 1,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "aze",
                    "initial": "12",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "paul",
                    "initial": "123",
                    "supp": "100"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "Kian Crist",
                    "initial": "12",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "Kian Crist",
                    "initial": "0",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "LOUBATA",
                    "initial": "12345098",
                    "supp": "123400"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "Douze Pixels",
                    "initial": "10000000",
                    "supp": "300000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "azer",
                    "initial": "1234",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        } 
      ]
   }



total_depenses: function () {

         
    let total = [];
     Object.entries (this.data) .forEach (([key, val]) => {
     total.push (val.initial)
      });
     return total.reduce (function (total, num) {return total + num});
      
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. You can filter out all `achat` arrays and then merge it. After that you can go through all elements and do the sum.

```js
const dataObject = {
    "data": [

        {
            "id": 1,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "aze",
                    "initial": "12",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "paul",
                    "initial": "123",
                    "supp": "100"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "Kian Crist",
                    "initial": "12",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "Kian Crist",
                    "initial": "0",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "LOUBATA",
                    "initial": "12345098",
                    "supp": "123400"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "Douze Pixels",
                    "initial": "10000000",
                    "supp": "300000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "azer",
                    "initial": "1234",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


const returnSum = data => {
    return [].concat.apply([], 
            data.map(el => el.achat))
            .reduce((acc,el) => acc + +el.initial, 0)
}

console.log(returnSum(dataObject.data))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const sum = info.data.map(x => x.achat) // Extract only the achat field
                    .flat() // Flatten the array Eg: [[1], [2], [3]] --> [1, 2, 3]
                    .map(x => +x.initial) // Extract the initial field ("+" is to convert string to integer)
                    .reduce((e, f) => e + f); // Calculate the sum
```

```js
let info = {
    "data": [

        {
            "id": 1,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "aze",
                    "initial": "12",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "paul",
                    "initial": "123",
                    "supp": "100"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "Kian Crist",
                    "initial": "12",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "Kian Crist",
                    "initial": "0",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "LOUBATA",
                    "initial": "12345098",
                    "supp": "123400"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "Douze Pixels",
                    "initial": "10000000",
                    "supp": "300000"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "achat": [
                {
                    "fournisseur": "azer",
                    "initial": "1234",
                    "supp": "0"
                }
            ]
        } 
      ]
    };
        
  const sum = info.data.map(x => x.achat) // Extract only the achat object
                    .flat() // Flatten the array Eg: [[1], [2], [3]] --> [1, 2, 3]
                    .map(x => +x.initial) // Extract the initial field ("+" is to convert string to integer)
                    .reduce((e, f) => e + f); // Calculate the sum
                    
  console.log("sum: " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like so:

```
const sum = dataObject.data
.map(x => parseInt(x.achat[0].initial))
.reduce((y, z) => y + z)

console.log(sum)
```